# How to fairly share bandwidth between IPs with tc?

Tags: linux, ip, bandwidth, tc

I have a linux router (d-link 320-nru) with tc installed.
I have some users' computers to fairly share bandwidth between them.
Also there is such complication as inconstant uplink bandwidth.

How can I configure tc to meet all these requirements?

Thanks in advance.